# Hibernate 3.6.7-final java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Timestamp format must be yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss[.fffffffff]

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, date, timestamp

I have this field in my entity.

```
@Column(name = "CREATED_DATE")
@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
@DateTimeFormat(style = "yyyy-MM-dd-HH.mm.ss.SSSSSS")
private Date createdDate;
```

When i use `TemporalType.TIMESTAMP` i get the following error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Timestamp format must be yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss[.fffffffff]
    at java.sql.Timestamp.valueOf(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.6.0_45]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.CharCommonAccessor.getTimestamp(CharCommonAccessor.java:544) ~[ojdbc6-11.2.0.2.0.jar:11.2.0.2.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CCharAccessor.getTimestamp(T4CCharAccessor.java:851) ~[ojdbc6-11.2.0.2.0.jar:11.2.0.2.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleResultSetImpl.getTimestamp(OracleResultSetImpl.java:1408) ~[ojdbc6-11.2.0.2.0.jar:11.2.0.2.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleResultSet.getTimestamp(OracleResultSet.java:512) ~[ojdbc6-11.2.0.2.0.jar:11.2.0.2.0]
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingResultSet.getTimestamp(DelegatingResultSet.java:300) ~[commons-dbcp-1.3.jar:1.3]
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingResultSet.getTimestamp(DelegatingResultSet.java:300) ~[commons-dbcp-1.3.jar:1.3]
    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.TimestampTypeDescriptor$2.doExtract(TimestampTypeDescriptor.java:62) ~[hibernate-core-3.6.7.Final.jar:3.6.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicExtractor.extract(BasicExtractor.java:64) ~[hibernate-core-3.6.7.Final.jar:3.6.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:254) ~[hibernate-core-3.6.7.Final.jar:3.6.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:250) ~[hibernate-core-3.6.7.Final.jar:3.6.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:230) ~[hibernate-core-3.6.7.Final.jar:3.6.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.hydrate(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:331) ~[hibernate-core-3.6.7.Final.jar:3.6.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.hydrate(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2283) ~[hibernate-core-3.6.7.Final.jar:3.6.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.loadFromResultSet(Loader.java:1527) ~[hibernate-core-3.6.7.Final.jar:3.6.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.instanceNotYetLoaded(Loader.java:1455) ~[hibernate-core-3.6.7.Final.jar:3.6.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRow(Loader.java:1355) ~[hibernate-core-3.6.7.Final.jar:3.6.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRowFromResultSet(Loader.java:611) ~[hibernate-core-3.6.7.Final.jar:3.6.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:829) ~[hibernate-core-3.6.7.Final.jar:3.6.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:274) ~[hibernate-core-3.6.7.Final.jar:3.6.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2533) ~[hibernate-core-3.6.7.Final.jar:3.6.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listUsingQueryCache(Loader.java:2319) ~[hibernate-core-3.6.7.Final.jar:3.6.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2268) ~[hibernate-core-3.6.7.Final.jar:3.6.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.criteria.CriteriaLoader.list(CriteriaLoader.java:119) ~[hibernate-core-3.6.7.Final.jar:3.6.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1716) ~[hibernate-core-3.6.7.Final.jar:3.6.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.impl.CriteriaImpl.list(CriteriaImpl.java:347) ~[hibernate-core-3.6.7.Final.jar:3.6.7.Final]
```

When i use `TemporalType.DATE` or `TemporalType.TIME` i get this error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: null
    at java.sql.Date.valueOf(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.6.0_45]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.CharCommonAccessor.getDate(CharCommonAccessor.java:490) ~[ojdbc6-11.2.0.2.0.jar:11.2.0.2.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CCharAccessor.getDate(T4CCharAccessor.java:820) ~[ojdbc6-11.2.0.2.0.jar:11.2.0.2.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleResultSetImpl.getDate(OracleResultSetImpl.java:759) ~[ojdbc6-11.2.0.2.0.jar:11.2.0.2.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleResultSet.getDate(OracleResultSet.java:410) ~[ojdbc6-11.2.0.2.0.jar:11.2.0.2.0]
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingResultSet.getDate(DelegatingResultSet.java:294) ~[commons-dbcp-1.3.jar:1.3]
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingResultSet.getDate(DelegatingResultSet.java:294) ~[commons-dbcp-1.3.jar:1.3]
    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.DateTypeDescriptor$2.doExtract(DateTypeDescriptor.java:62) ~[hibernate-core-3.6.7.Final.jar:3.6.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicExtractor.extract(BasicExtractor.java:64) ~[hibernate-core-3.6.7.Final.jar:3.6.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:254) ~[hibernate-core-3.6.7.Final.jar:3.6.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:250) ~[hibernate-core-3.6.7.Final.jar:3.6.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:230) ~[hibernate-core-3.6.7.Final.jar:3.6.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.hydrate(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:331) ~[hibernate-core-3.6.7.Final.jar:3.6.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.hydrate(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2283) ~[hibernate-core-3.6.7.Final.jar:3.6.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.loadFromResultSet(Loader.java:1527) ~[hibernate-core-3.6.7.Final.jar:3.6.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.instanceNotYetLoaded(Loader.java:1455) ~[hibernate-core-3.6.7.Final.jar:3.6.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRow(Loader.java:1355) ~[hibernate-core-3.6.7.Final.jar:3.6.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRowFromResultSet(Loader.java:611) ~[hibernate-core-3.6.7.Final.jar:3.6.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:829) ~[hibernate-core-3.6.7.Final.jar:3.6.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:274) ~[hibernate-core-3.6.7.Final.jar:3.6.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2533) ~[hibernate-core-3.6.7.Final.jar:3.6.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listUsingQueryCache(Loader.java:2319) ~[hibernate-core-3.6.7.Final.jar:3.6.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2268) ~[hibernate-core-3.6.7.Final.jar:3.6.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.criteria.CriteriaLoader.list(CriteriaLoader.java:119) ~[hibernate-core-3.6.7.Final.jar:3.6.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1716) ~[hibernate-core-3.6.7.Final.jar:3.6.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.impl.CriteriaImpl.list(CriteriaImpl.java:347) ~[hibernate-core-3.6.7.Final.jar:3.6.7.Final]
```

I've tried every format i could think of in `@DateTimeFormat` but nothing changes.

I'm switching from a DB2 database to an Oracle (org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect) one and i can't solve this error.

Comment: why not @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP) ?

Comment: I'm pretty sure your database does not support millisecond precision. Similarly, java doesn't support nanoseconds.

Comment: @ScaryWombat When i use it i get the Timestamp format must be yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss[.fffffffff] error.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch How can I check that? In my database i have inserted values like 2014-05-22-11.02.32.315000

Comment: for TIMESTAMP you do not need @DateTimeFormat

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28318/datatype.htm#i1847

Comment: @ElliottFrisch The column createdDate is CHAR(26) in my db.

Comment: @ScaryWombat I've removed the DateTimeFormat annotation but i still get the same error.

Comment: Then you've given hibernate the wrong column type.

Comment: if the column is CHAR(26) then you need to get it as a String

Comment: @ElliottFrisch And what should i give it? This was the way it was configured and worked fine with DB2.

Comment: `@DateTimeFormat` belongs to which package? it is not there in `Hibernate`

Comment: @user2065083 org.springframework.format.annotation.DateTimeFormat;

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with the domain object which is mapped with the DB.

check the Domain class and all the variable declaration. Somewhere it is declared as Date instead of long/String in the domain class, That is causing the problem.